How to extend classes in Lua
Use lib classic.
I have next code:
Combination = Object:extend()

function Combination:new(level, score)
self.curentCombinationValues = 0
self.curentCombination = {}
self.level =  level
self.score =  score 
end

NonPair = Combination:extend()

function NonPair:new()
NonPair.super:new(1, 2)
end

OnePair = Combination:extend()

function OnePair:new()
OnePair.super:new(1, 3)
end

When I create two objects, the second one replaces the variables of the inherited object, which means the first one also changes.
local one = NonPair()
local second = OnePair()

one.level  = second.level .
Why?

Can't reproduce, https://onecompiler.com/lua/433wcz5hr, please provide a [mre].

@shingo  add : print(one.score)  print(second.score)  and recive  3 - 3  but it was necessary to get 2 - 3

NonPair.super:new(1, 2) is syntactic sugar for NonPair.super.new(NonPair.super, 1, 2) (the same pattern applies for OnePair).
This means the contextual self inside Combination:new will not refer to the new instance (one), but rather the parent class itself (Combination). With this, self.level = level is then equivalent to Combination.level = level, setting a key-value pair on the class itself.
The call to OnePair.super:new(1, 3) overwrites the values that were set by NonPair.super:new(1, 2), so both one.level and second.level result in the same value (both invoking the __index metamethod to find the value on the parent class).
The correct pattern to use with this library is
NonPair = Combination:extend()

function NonPair:new()
  NonPair.super.new(self, 1, 2)
end

OnePair = Combination:extend()

function OnePair:new()
  OnePair.super.new(self, 1, 3)
end

as shown in the README.

exactly. you need a dota  instead a colon when calling the parent constructor
